# How to import a json file to parse it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Originally my Json data was in a php file together with code to parse it.
They look like:

main.php

```
<script>
var pdatabase= '{ "pobject" : [' +
'{ "pname":"Pikachu" , "pid":"1" },' +
'{ "pname":"Squirtle" , "pid":"2" },' +  
'{ "pname":"Justinbieber" , "pid":"3" }]}';
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    ppdatabase = JSON.parse(pdatabase);
    plenth=ppdatabase.pobject.length;
    test=console.log(plenth);
});
</script>
```

Then I found this is terrible to manage my Json data. So I migrate the Json data to a separate file named "obdatabase.json".

obdatabase.json

```
var pdatabase= '{ "pobject" : [' +
'{ "pname":"Pikachu" , "pid":"1" },' +
'{ "pname":"squirtle" , "pid":"2" },' +
'{ "pname":"Justinbieber" , "pid":"3" }]}';
```

In the main.php, after deleting original json data, I made two attempts to access the data and parse it,but failed.

First try

```
<script src="obdatabase.json"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    ppdatabase = JSON.parse(pdatabase);
    plenth=ppdatabase.pobject.length;
    test=console.log(plenth);
});
</script>
```

Second Try

```
<script>
$.get('obdatabase.json', function(pdatabase) {
    ppdatabase = JSON.parse(pdatabase);
    plenth=ppdatabase.pobject.length;
    test=console.log(plenth);
});
</script>
```

So how to fix this?

Comment: the easy way? your first approach but add a `var ppdatabase = YOUR JSON;` to the start of the file. Save and load it as normal javascript file. (to future commentators - iam aware that this is not the best solution)

Comment: don't try creating json manually ... there is no need for it and it is very error prone

Answer (score 0):

Define the content of the JSON file as

```
{
    "pobject": [{
        "pname": "Pikachu",
        "pid": "1"
    }, {
        "pname": "squirtle",
        "pid": "2"
    }, {
        "pname": "Justinbieber",
        "pid": "3"
    }]
}
```

Then use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) directly to and no need to use `JSON.parse()`

```
$.getJSON('obdatabase.json', function(pdatabase) {
    plenth=ppdatabase.pobject.length;
    test=console.log(plenth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JSON and JSON like object in javascript, JSON can't contain code, it should contain only JSON (e.g `{"foo":"bar"}`)

What you really want is a `obdatabase.js` file instead of a `obdatabase.json`

Answer (score 0):

See the link.
https://jsfiddle.net/bjfu45q4/

```
var pdatabase= '{ "pobject" : [' +
'{ "pname":"Pikachu" , "pid":"1" },' +
'{ "pname":"squirtle" , "pid":"2" },' +
'{ "pname":"Justinbieber" , "pid":"3" }]}';

OR

var pdatabase = {
    "pobject" : [
         {"pname" : "Pikachu", "pid" : "1"},
         {"pname" : "squirtle", "pid" : "2"},
         {"pname" : "Justinbieber", "pid" : "3"}
    ]
};

var tmpJson = JSON.parse(pdatabase);
console.log(tmpJson.pobject.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify that data to use it as a variable just to then convert it to an object using `JSON.parse`

If you had simply used:

```
var pdatabase = {
    "pobject" : [
        {"pname" : "Pikachu", "pid" : "1"},
        {"pname" : "squirtle", "pid" : "2"},
        {"pname" : "Justinbieber", "pid" : "3"}]
};
```

In the file or script tag you would be able to access the object directly